# Subnetting 2 subnets, 127 hosts on /24 class b network

Tags: subnet, ip-address

I have an upcoming exam in networks communication. One of the available tasks for training on subnetting is the following:

> Suppose you are an ISP with a 132.1.32.0/24 address block. If 2
>   customers require addresses for 127 and 60 computers respectively. Do
>   the address assignment.

Don't i need 1 bit for subnets and then will have only 126 hosts per subnet since 2^7-2 = 126 ,therefor not being able to satisfy the customer demanding 127 hosts.

Or is there some other way to solve this that have passed me by ?

Comment: There are no classes and haven't been since 1993 (20 years - seriously, you might not have been born when they abolished those things). Nobody should even mention them anymore outside of a history class.

Comment: Also, answer depends on how shady your teacher is. Since he's/she's apparently taught you about "classes" I'll assume he/she fits into the "those who can't, teach" category. The network ID can be used as an IP address too. So in a /25 you normally have `.0`, `.127` and 1 IP for a router (itself a "host" by the strict definition); and 125 "usable" IPs. If you assign `.0` to a  host it should work, and this might be what you're teacher is after. It's bad practice to use that IP however, and not guaranteed to work on all IP Stacks.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if that's the right answer for your exam but i would give 2 subnets to customer1:

```
subnet one: 132.1.32.0/25
subnet two: 132.1.32.128/30
```

and for customer2 i would start at the end of the /24 block

```
subnet: 132.1.32.192/26
```